# where I can find demo to combine SQL / PHP in Blackberry app?

Tags: php, sql, blackberry

I need help to programming an App that need a data from SQL Server and somehow I have to update the data too. The app will be a client side and the server will have all the database. did BB allow us to connect to PHP directly or I need to make a HTML so that page will run the JS?.

Can anyone help me, where I can find the demo? or sample about Sql and app?

I have already install eclipse and Blackberry SDK 7.1.

Comment: PHP is a language for generating websites. You can use it, among other things, to create webservices which expose data from an SQL database. But that's in no way relevant to Blackberry, because in that case any system could use them.

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume you are building a horoscope app:

You input a date and zodiac sing and you get your horoscope from the server.

In this case, your client can be build from few HTML pages styled with CSS.
If you need something more fancy you can use JavaScript.

On the server side, you will need running DataBase, and support for PHP (running Apache).
In the simple variant your client will send requests (from a Form or Ajax) to
**www.myServer.com/my_php_back_end.php** and will display the response.

This is just a simple scenario so you can form your question better.

[PHP_MySQL-Creating-Form](http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/PHP-MySQL-Creating-Form-Insert-Data-P280.html)